# Access value from an updated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

If my table looks like

```
+-----------+------------+
| OrderNo   | ShippedDate|   
+-----------+------------+
| 0         | 2013-01-03 |
| 1         | 2013-03-05 |    
| 2         | 2013-01-19 |
| 3         | NULL       | 
| 4         | NULL       | 
+-----------+------------+
```

and it got updated to

```
+-----------+------------+
| OrderNo   | ShippedDate|   
+-----------+------------+
| 0         | 2013-01-03 |
| 1         | 2013-03-05 |    
| 2         | 2013-01-19 |
| 3         | NULL       | 
| 4         | 2013-05-27 | 
+-----------+------------+
```

How do I access the OrderNo in which ShippedDate just got updated (in this case, 4)?

I am trying to create a trigger that will trigger after UPDATE on ShippedDate column and I need to get the OrderNo to do some comparisons with other table which has OrderNo as a foreign key.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

There are special tables **inserted** and **deleted** that hold the new value and old value after a update

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
-- You can create an After Update trigger like this:    
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[tableName] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @orderNo int;
    declare @shippedDate datetime;

    -- You can store what in the record in variables:
    select @orderNo=i.OrderNo from inserted i;  
    select @shippedDate=i.ShippedDate from inserted i;  

    -- You can check if the values were actually changed or not:
    if update(OrderNo)
            PRINT 'OrderNo updated.'
    if update(ShippedDate)
            PRINT 'ShippedDate was updated.'

GO
```